# Conditions for Feynman’s trick over unbounded set

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

If we integrate the function $f(x,t)\in C^1$ over a compact set the following is true:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{[a,b]}f(x,t)\:\mathrm{d}t=\int_{[a,b]} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)\:\mathrm{d}t $$
If we want to integrate over a unbounded region we can use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) to justify swapping the order of differentiation and integration.
However the function $f(x,t)=\mathrm{e}^{xt}$ is not bounded if we integrate it over $\mathbb{R}$ but we can differentiate under the indefinite integral. So what is the necessary and sufficient condition the swap the order of differentiation and integration for an indefinite integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Recall that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Uses_and_properties), an inverse integral of $f(x, t)$, respect to $t$, can be written as
$$\int f(x, t) dt = \int_0^t f(x, s) ds \quad \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R} \, .$$
Here writing $s$ or any other letter (different from $t$) is not important. From this, using the property you wrote, you get
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int f(x,t)\:\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^t f(x, s) \:\mathrm{d}s = \int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,s)\:\mathrm{d}s = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)\:\mathrm{d}t \quad \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Notice that the interval $[0, t]$ is compact.

This is not a necessary and sufficient condition (and I'm not aware of any), but this needs the same hypotheses of your previous property.